# Vue app, styles to html and body elements are not applied, I am using SCSS

Tags: html, vue.js, sass

I am trying to apply a font size among other styles to the root `html` and `body` elements, I have a styles folder that contains a couple of subfolders in it, then I import them in my .vue components. in the main.scss file I am applying styles to the universal selectors, and like i said to the `html` and `body`, the universal selectors styles gets applied along with any other element I choose manually, However, styles that I am trying to assign to the root elements are not applied.

```css
// this is my main.scss
// this code gets applied 
*, *::before, *::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.test {
  border: 2px solid red; 
 }

// this does NOt get applied
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
<template>
  <section class="Home">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="test">Hello world</h1>
      <p>this is a test</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
 @import './scss/main.scss
 
 
</style>
```

again, I am sure that I have no problems with compiling or importing my .scss files as some styles get applied successfully, I just don't understand html and body tags are not accepting the styles !! 
feel free to ask for more info if needed, thank in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
* {
  font-size: 62.5% !important;
  color: #777 !important;
}
```

If there is no other **!important** styles that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you give a class to your **body** tag and apply your style to a class rather than applying directly to an element tag.

Or even better if you set a **main div** under **body** tag, give it a class and style that instead:

```
// app.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="bodyContainer">
      //Content
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


// main.scss    
.bodyContainer {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  color: #777;
}
```